# Animate progress with filling the color of the border width of a UIImageView layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

I have am UIImageView and I have made it to be circle with a width layer like in this image :

[image]

User can update the image and upload new one, I have a progress call back while image is uploaded. What I want is to animate the border with color while the image is uploaded, for example when user click upload the border start from top with green color and fill the width according to the progress.

I tried with this code:

```
        CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointZero radius:27 startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:2 * M_PI - M_PI_2 clockwise:YES].CGPath;
        circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        circle.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        circle.lineWidth = 4;

        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        animation.duration = 10;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        animation.fromValue = @(0);
        animation.toValue = @(1);
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        [circle addAnimation:animation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

        [imageView.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
        [imageView.layer addSublayer:circle];
```

But It shows the circle in wrong position and this aproch does not take a progress, it's static is there any way to fill the border width of the layer of UIImageView according to progress ?

Comment: Hi try this... https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mbcircularprogressbar

Comment: Thank you for your link, but  I really want to implement it my self and also use the layer of the UIImageView and animate the fill the border color according to a progress value from 0 to 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIImageView` is meant to show the images. I would not suggest changing it's behaviour. Even though you subclass the UIImageView and try to draw something in it, the drawRect of it will not get called. Let the imageView be `imageView` and use `UIView` for the rest
I suggest you to subclass the `UIView` and then draw a bezier path in it and animate the bezier path curve, You can later add the imageview to the uiview .

`UIView` subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self drawImageHolderViewFrame:rect startAngle:_startAngle];
}

- (void)drawImageHolderViewFrame: (CGRect)frame startAngle: (CGFloat)startAngle
{
    CGRect ovalRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) , CGRectGetMinY(frame) , frame.size.width-10, frame.size.height-10);
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [ovalPath addArcWithCenter: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(ovalRect), CGRectGetMidY(ovalRect)) radius: CGRectGetWidth(ovalRect) / 2 startAngle: -91 * M_PI/180 endAngle: -startAngle * M_PI/180 clockwise: YES];
    [UIColor.redColor setStroke];
    ovalPath.lineWidth = 2;
    [ovalPath stroke];
}
```

`viewController` class:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    _imageHolderView=[[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
    _imageHolderView.startAngle=90;
    _imageHolderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview: _imageHolderView];
    [self startTImer];
}

-(void)startTImer{
    NSTimer *timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(animateBorder) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)animateBorder{
    if (_startAngle<=-270) {
        _startAngle=90;
    }
    _startAngle--;
    _imageHolderView.startAngle=_startAngle;
    [_imageHolderView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This would give you:

[image]

Now you can add the imageview as a subview to the view you just created.

[image]

Comment: wish that I can up vote your answer more than once ;)

Comment: once would be fine :P!!

Comment: But can you please let me know how to change it to work with progress from 0 to 1 because the progress will be the upload of the image and not an `NSTimer` ? something like `myCustomView.progress  = value` where value from 0 to 1

Comment: the upload progress will be returned as values in between 0 to 1 ?

Comment: In that case you can use the condiiton as _startAngle*900 where the startAngle will be your value from 0.1 to 1

Answer (score 3):

Please try the code below:

```
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(29, 29) radius:27 startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:2 * M_PI - M_PI_2 clockwise:YES].CGPath;    
circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;   
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;   
circle.lineWidth = 4;


CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];     
animation.duration = 10;   
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;    
animation.fromValue = @(0);    
animation.toValue = @(1);    
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];    
[circle addAnimation:animation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];    



[imageCircle.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];    
[imageCircle.layer addSublayer:circle];
```